# Check if stdin pipe is empty in C

Tags: c, stdin

I am using user input to fill a 2d array. A user inputs numbers in one line and I then use nested loops to fill the array like so:

```
//User inputs: "1 2 3 4 5"

for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
    }
 }
```

However, the problem is if the user enters 5 ints when there is room for 6, it just waits for another input. How can I detect if there are insufficient numbers?

I have tried using this but it didn't work:

```
for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++){
        if (!feof(stdin)){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
        else{
            printf("insufficient datapoints\n");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: if `scanf()` don't return `EOF` the pipe is not close.

Comment: @ccpgh how would I do that?

Comment: Use `fgets` and `strtok` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish your goal would involve using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` to read in a line of input at a time. Then `strtok()` can be used to break the line of input into tokens, and `strtol()` can be used to parse the tokens into numbers. Compared with `scanf()`, it is much easier to use `fgets` to handle unstructured user input.

The code below does this. If there are too many elements on an input row, too few elements, or if one of the elements is not a valid number, a message is printed and the row must be entered again.

As each line is entered by the user, `strtok()` is used to break the line into tokens. The list of token delimiters is stored in `delims[]`. Note that tokens may be separated by spaces or tabs; the delimiters themselves are not part of the token, so including `\r` and `\n` ensures that these characters will not be part of the final token in a line.

When a token is found, `strtol()` is used to convert it to an integer, if possible. After the call to `strtol()`, the pointer `tail` points to the first character in the token that was not part of a number; if `tail` points to the `NUL` terminator, then the entire string was parsed as a number, otherwise the input is considered bad and the row must be entered again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE  1000

int main(void)
{
    size_t r = 3;
    size_t c = 5;
    size_t i, j;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    char *token;
    char *tail;
    const char delims[] = " \t\r\n";
    int arr[r][c];
    int temp_val;

    printf("Enter rows of %zu data elements:\n", c);

    for(i = 0; i < r; i++){
        j = 0;

        if (fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
            perror("Error in fgets()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        token = strtok(buffer, delims);
        while (token != NULL) {
            temp_val = strtol(token, &tail, 10);
            if (*tail == '\0') {
                arr[i][j] = temp_val;
                ++j;
            } else {                // token not a valid number
                j = 0;
                break;
            }

            if (j > c) {            // too many input values
                break;
            }

            token = strtok(NULL, delims);
        }

        if (j != c) {
            printf("insufficient datapoints\n");
            --i;                    // enter row again
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            printf("%5d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
Enter rows of 5 data elements:
1 2 3 4
insufficient datapoints
1 2 3 4 5 6
insufficient datapoints
1 x 2 3 4
insufficient datapoints
1 2 3 4 x
insufficient datapoints
1 2 3 4 5 x
insufficient datapoints
1 2x 3 4 5
insufficient datapoints
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
 3  4  5    6 7
    1    2    3    4    5
    2    3    4    5    6
    3    4    5    6    7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use peek ahead in the stream and test characters before you actually consume them. (Well sort of in c).

You can use this to ignore whitespace (you will need to do this).

You can also use this peeked value to indicate if insufficient characters have been input.

The peek needs to be done BEFORE the actual read (scanf).

Added rough example code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int r=3; 
int c=2;

int arr[100][100]; // FIX magic

int main(int argc, char** argv[]) {

  for(int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<c; j++) {

      if (feof(stdin)) {
        // error check and error / normal exit etc.
        printf("eof\n");
      }

      char c=getchar();

      if (c=='\n') {
        // error check and error / normal exit here
        printf("newline\n");

      } else if (isspace(c)) {
        // advance and remove them - watch for end of stream when winding
        printf("advance and discard whiitespace\n");

      } else { // add check for isdigit
        // push back
        ungetc(c, stdin);
        printf("ungetc\n");
      }

      scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);  
      printf("got %d\n", arr[i][j]);   
    }    
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This test app just sits there and does nothing if the pipe is empty, which defeats the purpose of checking to see if it was empty in the first place... So, not sure what this was supposed to accomplish.